# Prove convergence in distribution(weakly convergence) using Helly-Bray Theorem

Tags: probability

The problem goes like this:
Let $\mu_n, n\geq 1$ and $\mu$ be probability measures on $(R,\mathcal{B}(R))$. Suppose that, for any $a<b\in R$ with $\mu(\{a\})=0=\mu(\{b\})$, it holds that $\mu_n((a,b]) \to \mu((a,b])$ as $n\to \infty$. Show that $\mu_n \Rightarrow \mu$.

This is an exam question in my probability course, and I strongly feel Helly-Bray Theorem is the only choice. I know Borel $\sigma$-algebra are generated by the set of all $(a,b]$, but I cannot relate $\mu_n((a,b]) \to \mu((a,b])$ to $\mu_n(A) \to \mu(A)$ for any $A\in \mathcal{B}(R)$

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, the Borel sets are generated by half-open intervals...

Comment: @Ian Yeah, but how exactly will that help to prove the statement? Thanks

Comment: hint: converence in set of generators implies convergence in every generated subset.